# NITGEN eNBSP SDK Sample C# Not Working

Tags: fingerprint, mifare

I have NAC-5000 device here and already connected to my local server.I tested the functionality and its ok and working thru AccessManager. I use fingerprint and Card(Mifare) to authenticate.

My Problem is i want to **authenticate on the device** using card or fingerprint using SDK Sample C# but the code is not working **NBioAPI_OpenDevice error:0102**

The Device is connected to my local LAN

```
private void btnRegist_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        NBioAPI.Type.HFIR hNewFIR;
        uint nUserID = 0;

        // Get User ID
        try 
        {
            int test = Convert.ToInt32(textUserID.Text, 10);
            if (test == 0)
                throw(new Exception());
        } 
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User ID must be have numeric type and greater than 0.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        nUserID = Convert.ToUInt32(textUserID.Text, 10);

        // Get FIR data
        m_NBioAPI.OpenDevice(NBioAPI.Type.DEVICE_ID.AUTO);

        uint ret = m_NBioAPI.Enroll(out hNewFIR, null);
        if (ret != NBioAPI.Error.NONE) 
        {
            DisplayErrorMsg(ret);
            m_NBioAPI.CloseDevice(NBioAPI.Type.DEVICE_ID.AUTO);
            return;
        }

        m_NBioAPI.CloseDevice(NBioAPI.Type.DEVICE_ID.AUTO);

        // Regist FIR to IndexSearch DB
        NBioAPI.IndexSearch.FP_INFO[] fpInfo;
        ret = m_IndexSearch.AddFIR(hNewFIR, nUserID, out fpInfo);
        if (ret != NBioAPI.Error.NONE)
        {
            DisplayErrorMsg(ret);
            return;
        }

        // Add item to list of SearchDB
        foreach  (NBioAPI.IndexSearch.FP_INFO sampleInfo in fpInfo)
        {
            ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
            listItem.Text = sampleInfo.ID.ToString();
            listItem.SubItems.Add(sampleInfo.FingerID.ToString());
            listItem.SubItems.Add(sampleInfo.SampleNumber.ToString());
            listSearchDB.Items.Add(listItem);
        }

        textUserID.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textUserID.Text) + 1);
    }
```

i run this on 64-bit OS Win 7